# add the corresponding cells of two arrays

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I am stuck on a problem. I am supposed to add the correspond cells of two different arrayd and fill a third array with the sum to the correspond cell so for example I have ar1 = {4,6,3} and ar2 = {8,5,6} and I have to fill a third array that is empty with the sum like so ar3 = {12,11,9}. Here is my code so far:

```
    class sumOfArrays
    {
     public static void main ( String[] args )
     {
        int[] arrA   = { 11, -27,  89,  17}; 
        int[] arrB   = {-3,  24, -9, -16};
        int[] sum    = {  0,   0,   0,   0};


       for(int i = 0; i < arrA.length - 1; i++)
       {
         for(int j = 0; i < arrB.length - 1; i++)
             {
                      sum[arrA[i] + arrB[j]];

                 }


       }




System.out.println("sum: " + sum[0]+"," + sum[1] + ","  + sum[2] + ","  + sum[3] );
```

}
}

I am stuck and would like a little guidance. Thank you all in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

You calculated the sum of the corresponding numbers from the two arrays, but then you used it as an index into `sum` and did nothing with it.

Just assign the sum to the corresponding index `i` in the `sum` array.

Also, you don't need 2 nested loops.  Just use one nested loop for `i`, which will be used to access all arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing an index in sum[] rather than storing the values. It should look more like this:

```
sum[i] = arrA[i] + arrB[i];
```

Also, if you use just one loop, you can reference the same element in all three arrays in the way I've done above.

Finally, you should keep iterating until **i < arrA.length**, not **i < arrA.length - 1**. otherwise you are skipping an element at the end.

Answer (score 0):

IN your example, you would like to populate the sum array of arrA an and arryB, and the length of arrA and arrB is equal.

Then you need to change the inner for-loop. Code, like `sum[arrA[i] + arrB[j]]`;, is used to get the value with the index of (**arrA[i] + arrB[j]]** ) from sum array. This will encounter a syntax error when trying to compiling. Because you does not do the assignment, like `int value =  sum[arrA[i] + arrB[j]];`

From

```
    for(int j = 0; i < arrB.length - 1; i++)
    {
                 sum[arrA[i] + arrB[j]];

    }
```

To

```
sum[i] = arrA[i] + arrB[i];
```

then you will get the right result. Output in console is below:

```
sum: 8,-3,80,0
```